# How can I order a discrete x axis?

Tags: geom-bar

I would like to order my scale so that the values are in the same order as in my data frame, beginning with WT End of Night and ending with MT End of Day. When I hit run a plot appears that shows exactly the opposite order.

I´ve already tried scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("WT","MT","WT",MT")) but r removed all 4 rows because they were "containing missing values".
I also tried different combinations with rev() but this didn´t work either.
Thanks!

```
    glucose <- c(793,429,658,2265)
    Plant <-c("WT","MT","WT","MT")
    day <-  c("End of Night", "End of Night", "End of Day", "End of Day")
    Glucose <- data.frame(Plant, glucose, day)
    ggplot(Glucose, aes( x=day, y= glucose, fill=Plant))+
      geom_bar(stat="identity", position ="dodge")
```

Comment: no idea how to an image of my plot to y request...

Comment: Tag order is being removed from the system. Please don't put it back. There is nothing wrong with your question otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can try re-ordering the levels of the factor `Plant`, so that `WT` is the first level (by default, the order is alphabetical).

```
Glucose %>%
  mutate(Plant = fct_relevel(Glucose$Plant, "WT", "MT")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = day, y = glucose, fill = Plant)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

Also note that `geom_col()` is a substitute to `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`.